# Mouseover fade effect in bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my web application and I am using the 'img-responsive' class to get the following result

[image]

My question is how can I add a mouseover fade effect. I used the following code to get my desired effect but I am not sure how to incorporate that with the bootstrap theme. I tried to add the fade out css but I am not getting that right:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>
<style>
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working to me: http://jsfiddle.net/9nh4n/. Are you sure your HTML structure / classes are correct?

Comment: @mtaube, the js and css work but I need to use it with my bootstrap. The image uses the img-responsive class and since I need that how can I separately or integrate that with it.

Comment: Could you show your actual HTML then, with the Bootstrap markup? It should be as simple as changing a class in the CSS / JS or adding a class to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.button{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Fmpx/)

Comment: sorry i guess I wasn't clear, but the code I have works, but how can I integrate that with the bootstrap class. If I use my code I need to overwrite that. I want the responsiveness and the fade effect

Comment: you dont have access to the stylesheets?

Comment: @CSharpDev4Evr just replace my `.button` code above with `img.a` and of course remove the `width`, `height`, and `background` I added.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're linking to your custom CSS (OR using a  tag) **AFTER** the link to Bootstrap's CSS

Then try this:

```
img.a {
    opacity: 1;   /* redundant, but helps illustrate what is happening */
    -webkit-transition: 400ms; /* or however long you want */
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms; /* or however long you want */
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
img.a:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

If that doesn't do anything, you can try overriding the CSS by adding
**!important** before the semicolon at the end of the line

eg.

```
opacity: 0 !important;
```

This should have the effect you're looking for and not affect the responsiveness.